# How to stop text in a button control from breaking the word up onto multiple lines in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

I have a Windows Forms project that sets button text based on variables. The font is quite large for readability, but it means that some words are too long to fit in the button nicely, and the last few characters break onto multiple lines.

Is there an algorithm or property I can use to resize the text inside the button to prevent this from happening?

I don't want to try to fit the text on one line, I just want to stop the text from splitting words up.

Comment: Its been a long time since i worked with winforms and i don't remember an easy way to do that. you may a) set `AutoEllipsis` to `true`. That should disable the line breaking but may add ellipsis. or b) You measure your String with `Graphics.MeasureString` and check if it fits manually.

Comment: @Pretasoc Both of those options sound quite promising. I'll try the latter and see what happens

Comment: If you resize the Font to let the text fit the Button client size, you might have text with different Font sizes all over the place. Not a great view. Maybe let [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) (with [TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags)) draw the text. It does a better job than the default AutoEllipse. Unless you need to show the full text of the Button at all times.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to resize the font, you could try to detect when the text has reached the bounds of the button and then reduce the font size. Here's some code to get you started, but I'm not sure how to determine the length where text will start wrapping based on the button width. Perhaps there's some other property for that which I couldn't find.

```
// Get some info from the button control
var graphics = button1.CreateGraphics();
var font = button1.Font;
var textWidth = graphics.MeasureString(button1.Text, font).Width;

// Not sure what the magic formula is to determine when the word wraps
if (textWidth > button1.Width - 25)
{
    // Assign a new font based on the old one, but smaller
    button1.Font = new Font(font.FontFamily, font.Size - 1,
        font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Comment: If the Font should be redefined, you don't really need to measure the Font, you just need to measure the scale. If the `[Text].Width is > [Control].ClientRectangle.Width`,  `=>` `scale = [Control].ClientRectangle.Width / [Text].Width`, then apply the transformation: `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale)`.  Some `StringFormatFlags` or `TextFormatFlags` (depending on what's drawing the string) do the rest. This will work with both word wrapping and without (single line).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoSize` of the button to `"false"`:

```
Button1.AutoSize = "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but there should not be any algorithm which can help you here (even AI algorithms). Constraint is you want to keep font size and button size same. However you can do following which could solve your problem.

1. Use abbreviated text. e.g. First few words(characters)/ Initials of text. Generally contacts list on android mobiles, skype, or any other communicator shows initials if avatar is not set.
2. Show some part of text on button and when mouse hovers then show full text by resizing the button or on tooltip.
3. Add some space on form which will show full text when mouse is hovered on any button on it. So a common label on form which will show full button text when mouse is hovered on any button.
4. If texts are fixed/static then introduce some icons on button instead of text and show full text as tooltip.

~Nilesh

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am happy to change the font size in order to fit the text

Comment: Then try to get the length of text in pixels, see if it fits in your button. Try multiple font sizes, till minimum font size you want to allow. Otherwise adopt one of the approach listed above.

Comment: using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
{
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString("Hello there", new Font("Segoe UI", 11, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point));
}